# Finding value when time series is above a threshold more than 1 day in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has a datetime index and a time series of integer values 1 per day. From this, I want to identify occurrences where the timeseries is above a threshold for at least 2 consecutive days.  For these events, I want to count how many of these occur over the entire span and the start date of each one.

One of the issues is making sure I don't over count the occurrences when the event lasts more than 2 days, as long as the values stay over the threshold it should only be 1 event whether it lasts 2 days of 10 days.

I can do this using a function with lots of if statements but it's very kludgy. I want to learn a more pandas/pythonic way of doing it.

I started by looking at a masked version of the data of only the values that were above the threshold (arbitrary here) and using diff() which seemed promising but I'm still stuck.  Any help is appreciated.

```
dates = pd.date_range('2012-01-01', periods=100, freq='D')
values = np.random.randint(100, size=len(dates))
df = pd.DataFrame({'timeseries':values}, index=dates)
df.loc[df['timeseries'] > arb_thr].index.to_series().diff().head(20)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of booleans to flag the rows which are above the threshold, then `cumsum` these to create the artificial groups and finally groupby on them:

```py
arb_thr = 20

df = df.reset_index()
grps = df["timeseries"].lt(arb_thr).cumsum()

result = df.groupby(grps).agg(
    min_date=("index", "min"),
    max_date=("index", "max"),
    count=("timeseries", "count")
).rename_axis(None, axis=0)
```

```
     min_date   max_date  count
0  2012-01-01 2012-01-09      9
1  2012-01-10 2012-01-11      2
2  2012-01-12 2012-01-12      1
3  2012-01-13 2012-01-22     10
4  2012-01-23 2012-01-24      2
5  2012-01-25 2012-02-04     11
6  2012-02-05 2012-02-07      3
7  2012-02-08 2012-02-08      1
8  2012-02-09 2012-02-10      2
9  2012-02-11 2012-02-12      2
10 2012-02-13 2012-02-15      3
11 2012-02-16 2012-02-20      5
12 2012-02-21 2012-02-21      1
13 2012-02-22 2012-02-23      2
14 2012-02-24 2012-02-25      2
15 2012-02-26 2012-03-04      8
16 2012-03-05 2012-03-07      3
17 2012-03-08 2012-03-20     13
18 2012-03-21 2012-03-22      2
19 2012-03-23 2012-03-23      1
20 2012-03-24 2012-03-24      1
21 2012-03-25 2012-03-28      4
22 2012-03-29 2012-03-29      1
23 2012-03-30 2012-04-01      3
24 2012-04-02 2012-04-08      7
25 2012-04-09 2012-04-09      1
```

Comment: This actually returns something a little different than what I was looking for but a slight tweak and it works great.

My goal was to get the number of events that are at least 2 days long and when they started.  Your approach gives all the days grouped in chunks.  To get the number of events that are at least 2 days long, I can do

    len(result[result['count'] > 2]) # or result[result['count'] > 2].count()

The start days are off by 1 day too early so if I shift the start dates of the events where count is > 2 by 1 I get the proper start date.  Thanks again!